# Intellij Cannot resolve table "...."

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, intellij-idea

Tudo bem? Estou com uma dúvida. Estou criando uma API com Spring Boot e SpringData, Hibernate, ao tentar resolver um relacionamento ManyToMany o IntelliJ exibiu um erro

> Cannot resolve table [nome_da_tabela]

Procurei nos fóruns algumas possíveis soluções, add o h2 database (o banco que estou usando) e defini `assing data source` mas sem sucesso. Alguém pode me dar um help por favor.

Obs: No **`settings >> inspections`** eu alterei para exibir um alerta.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Isso não é bem um erro, é mais um aviso do IntelliJ. Se você usa a versão Ultimate, a IDE pode se conectar com o banco de dados que você usa e (entre outras coisas) verificar se os nomes que você passa em anotações como *@Table* e *@Column* são válidos.

Se tu usa o h2 a partir do Spring Boot, tenta subir a API e manter ligada enquanto programa, assim o IntelliJ consegue se comunicar com o DB para fazer a validação corretamente, ou então desative a extensão de Database Connection pra evitar isso.

Exemplo do comportamento normal da extensão, quando conectada ao meu banco de dados Postgres local, ao passar o mouse sobre o nome de uma tabela:
[image: Exemplo de como o IntelliJ se comporta com a conexão configurada corretamente]

Comment: Entendi, cara. Tava batendo a cabeça aqui achando que meu codigo nao ia subir. Obrigado pela resposta.